# grails-3.3.9 on windows doesn't have run-app command

Tags: grails

I installed grails-3.3.9 pn windows 10 today (I also installed JDK from Oracle 1.8.0_191).
When I type "grails create-app hello", the command is completed successfully.
When  I type "grails run-app", grails gives the following message:
C:\Users\U1>grails run-app
Usage:
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin

### | Available Profiles

- angular - A profile for creating Grails applications with Angular 5+
- rest-api - Profile for REST API applications
- base - The base profile extended by other profiles
- angularjs - A profile for creating applications using AngularJS
- plugin - Profile for plugins designed to work across all profiles
- profile - A profile for creating new Grails profiles
- react - A profile for creating Grails applications with a React frontend
- react-webpack - A profile for creating Grails applications with a React frontend using Webpack
- webpack - A profile for creating applications with node-based frontends using webpack 2
- web - Profile for Web applications
- rest-api-plugin - Profile for REST API plugins
- vue - A profile for creating Grails applications with a Vue.js frontend
- web-jboss7 - A Profile for Creating a JBoss 7.1 EAP Project
- web-plugin - Profile for Plugins designed for Web applications

Type 'grails help' or 'grails -h' for more information.

C:\Users\U1>grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.3.9

## | JVM Version: 1.8.0_191

I downloaded the package once again from the site and re-installed, but the problem continues.
Any idea about what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To run the app you need to be in the same folder as the grails app. `cd hello` then `grails run-app`

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Comment: Great, glad it worked. You can accept the answer and I get some fake internet points. Welcome to Stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the Grails app is essentially a Gradle-based project, you should run in Win10's `cmd` with:

```
>gradlew.bat bootRun
```